# Exclude some child members from getting validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

To register new members I have a ViewModel named `UserRegisterModel`. this model gets two kind of address from user, his `HomeAddress` which is **required** and his `WorkAddress` which is **optional**. To get addresses I use a complex type named `ContactEntryModel`. I decorated my ContactEntryModel members with `[Required]` attribute which cause both home and work address get validated automatically.

I'm searching for a solution to mark WorkAddress as **Ignored** or **Excluded** and by that telling the validatation engine to stop validating WorkAddress child properties even though they decorated with validation attributes.

```
public class UserRegisterModel
    {
        [StringLength(50), Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50), Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10), Required]
        public string IdCardNo { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100), Email]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public ContactEntryModel HomeContact { get; set; }  //Required

        public ContactEntryModel WorkContact { get; set; }  //Optional
     }


   public class ContactEntryModel
    {
        [MaxLength(4), Required]
        public string TelPrefix { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10), Required]
        public string Tel { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Required]
        public string Province { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50), Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(300), Required]
        public string AddressLine { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I ended up creating two different ContactEntryModel, one for required addresses and the other for optional addresses. to keep these two models compatible I've used a base class which contains all members without any Validation attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a custom view model that is decorated appropriately to your situation.

Another version would be to tell your model binder to ignore the fields (this also skips the validation). You can do this using the Bind attribute:

```
[Bind(Exclude="WorkAddress")]
public ActionResult DoSomething(UserRegisterModel model)
{
    //controller code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but excluding the property from binding also make it unchangeable by user. I don't want that, I just want to make it an optional property (user still should be able to enter his WorkAddress if he wants to)

Comment: so why not remove the required attribute then?

Comment: because I have one Contact which is `required` and one which is `optional`, please read my question again to see what I meant

Comment: I'm already using a custom viewmodel, the point is I don't want to have 6 different member in my model for each address entry while some models may have 3 or more different address entry, so I aggregated those entries in another viewmodel named `ContactEntryModel`, now i need some kind of conditional validation.