# Exclude <input type='file'> from ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following file input tag in the "Create" View:

```
<input type="file" id="RequestFile" name="RequestFile"/>
@Html.ValidationMessage("RequestFile")
```

The  ViewModel contains this corresponding property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a file")]
public HttpPostedFileBase RequestFile { get; set; }
```

This works fine in the "Create" View, but in the "Edit" View, I get ModelState.Isvalid as false. Using the same ViewModel I would like to exclude this field from validations because I would not want to upload the file again.

I tried simply disabling the input tag like this:

```
<input type="file" id="RequestFile" name="RequestFile" disabled/>
```

This has a disabled input control but the Validation still fired.

Also applying the BindAttribute in the Controller did not work ([see this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894329/exclude-some-child-members-from-getting-validated))

Ideally (I know it sounds unlikely), if there is a server-side solution to this, please post  your thoughts. If there is a small client-side trick, please let me know!

Comment: `ModelState.Remove("RequestFile");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best ways are remove the property altogether, and always access it directly from the form collection (and manually validate it) or manually remove the model state error using the property name (as @cheesemacfly has in his comment, `ModelState.Remove("RequestFile")`).  The latter makes it very easy to fix then.

Comment: Thanks, the FormCollection method also should work. We'd be ignoring model binding in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use form.onsubmit to check to see it document.getElementById("RequestFile").value is not null/empty and cancel the submit if it is.

something like

```
<form onsubmit="if(!document.getElementById('RequestFile').value){alert('Please select a file.');return false;}" >
<input type="file" id="RequestFile" name="RequestFile" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

return false cancels the submission.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7HY/1/

or put it in the click event of the submit button itself

http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7HY/3/

Comment: I would like to submit the form with the empty File in the "Edit" View. I wanted to know if we could ignore the field in that case.